# How do I access my Apache Directory Listing on my site hosted by Hostgator

Tags: apache, directory, cpanel, web-hosting

I recently deployed and am hosting a site through Hostgator. I would like to access the sites apache directory listing, but am unsure the steps how.

I have tried finding videos on setting up a apache directory, but most are through linux or locally set up. I would like to access mine through my Hostgator hosted domain. (I imagine it'd be through the CPanel).